# How to programmatically covert a function-like rule to a pure function?

Tags: functions, pure-function, meta-programming

Is there a programmatic way to convert a *Mathematica* rule that acts like a typical mathematical function of one variable into the equivalent pure function? For example, the code should convert

```
f[x_] := x Sin[x^2]
```

into

```
Function[# Sin[#^2]]
```

and also convert

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{0,x<8.}, {2.5,8.<=x<18},{0,x>18}}]
```

into

```
Function[ Piecewise[{{0,#<8.}, {2.5,8.<=#<10},{0,#>18}}] ]
```

It's important that the result not reference the original function or the symbol used for it, so that the resulting pure function continues to work even if the original function-like rule is redefined or cleared.

Thanks...

Comment: To clarify: I need to write code that can take any function-like rule it's handed, and convert it into a pure function. Let's instantiate this as a function `ruleToFunction[rule_]:=...` that returns a pure function corresponding to whatever rule it was given. So, `ruleToFunction[f]` would return `Function[# Sin[#^2]]`, using my above example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ClearAll[ruleToFunction, f1, f2];

ruleToFunction[func_] := Function[, Evaluate@func[Slot[1]]];

g[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < 8.}, {2.5, 8. <= x < 18}, {0, x > 18}}]

f1 = ruleToFunction[g]
ClearAll[g];
f1@10

f[x_] := x Sin[x^2]

f2 = ruleToFunction[f]
ClearAll[f];
f2@10
```

[image]

Comment: It works! (I removed the comma in your definition of `ruleToFunction`, and it still seemed to work. Having a comma without anything before it freaks me out. Is that equivalent, or does that comma serve an important role?)

Comment: It's an undocumented form of `Function` (null first arg.). IIRC, it used to require null (or just comma), might have changed in later versions...Yep, just checked, w/o comma is fine.

Comment: Thanks much for the accept - do note, *Simon*'s answer is every bit as good (the `body` is just a placeholder that gets rewritten to a function of the result of your function (g in his example)). Deserves upvotes...

Comment: I think the Null argument is required only if you want to use the third argument (Attributes).

Answer (score 14):

You may already have discovered that something like `g[#]&` doesn't work - this is because `Function` has the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) Attribute, so its argument (`g[#]` in this case) doesn't get evaluated. The solution is to force `g[#]` to evaluate. Rasher showed what one way to do that, by using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html), whose specific purpose is to force evaluation of arguments that would normally be held unevaluated.

Another way is to create the `Function` with a dummy body, then replace that body with the result of evaluating `g[#]`. Like this:

```
func = body & /. body -> g[#]
(* Piecewise[{{0, #1 < 8.}, {2.5, 8. <= #1 < 10}}, 0] & *)

func[9]
(* 2.5 *)
```

As is often the case in *Mathematica*, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing. Here are a few more.

Use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) (a lexical scoping construct) to inject the evaluated expression into the `Function`:

```
func = With[{body = g[#]}, body &]
```

Wrap the expression to be evaluated in a Head which does not hold its arguments (such as `List`) and use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to replace that head with `Function`:

```
func = Function @@ {g[#]}
```

Use the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `g` as a replacement rule directly:

```
func = g[#] & /. DownValues[g]
```

Use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) (a dynamic scoping construct) to evaluate `g[#]&` in an environment where `Function` temporarily has no meaning and no special Attributes:

```
func = Block[{Function}, g[#] &]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What is "body"? Will this exact code work for any function-like rule, or only for my example `g[x]`?

Comment: Clean and cute. +1

Comment: DownValues solution is one of kind, +1

Comment: Okay, thanks for elaborating. I believe I understand now. And you're right, the first thing I tried was `g[#]&`.